# what tags should I remove to make an html page safe?

Tags: javascript, html, sanitization

I have a program that "sanitizes" web pages.  I coded it to remove script tags, and any code between the start and end "script" tag.  I remove any attributes of tags such as "onclick" or "onblur" or on-anything, since these can execute javascript.  I remove iframe tags, because they can contain another web page, which could have its own script.

The idea of all this is to prevent malicious scripts from executing before the user gets the page.  Of course he could just turn off JavaScript in his browser, but this html is presented as part of my own web page, and my own webpage needs JavaScript turned on.

My question is this:  Am I missing anything dangerous?

Comment: Any external js files which referenced from this html page?

Comment: "Am I missing anything dangerous?" — Yes. Don't use a blacklist. Use a whitelist.

Comment: @Quentin Best comment I have seen all day

Comment: ItayB: I do remove any external.js files.   Quentin: I use a whitelist for tags, a blacklist for attributes.